# Calibrating multiple binary SVM classifiers for one-vs-all multi-class classification

Tags: svm, text-mining, posterior, multi-class

I'm classifying text using the one-vs-all approach.  There are three classes.  I've trained 3 different binary SVM classifiers using 10-fold cross-validation.  The accuracy of the binary classifiers is fairly high (above 0.8 for all three classes).  Where I'm stuck is utilizing the result of the 3 classifiers to output the most likely class for a sample.  Since it's not meaningful to compare the classifier outputs directly, I'm using [Platt's technique](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.41.1639) (PDF is available) to calibrate them.  The graph below shows the calibration results:

[image]

The top row is the histogram of the classifier outputs.  The bottom row is the posterior probability for each example.  This graph is analogous to Figures 1 and 2 of Platt's paper.

Since the sigmoid fits look good, I think I've implemented the fitting algorithm *described by the pseudo-code at the end of the paper) correctly.  However, I don't get good classification results in the end.  Specifically, there are too many "class 3" false positive.  There are almost none "class 2" true positives.

My questions are:

- Can anybody see what could be wrong?
- What should I try next?  Should I scrap one-vs-all and do one-vs-one?
- Does one-vs-one require a similar type of calibration?  Or can you just use the sign of the SVM output to determine the winner of a particular vote?